# Why Gradle is downloading every time?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Whenever I open a fresh project, Gradle is downloaded each time. Actually it is one shot, otherwise any changes in gradle.properties.

I have downloaded latest version of Gradle and set environmental variables.

So my question is any way to change this downloading each time to get system level Gradle?

Note: I have set Gradle file location in Android studio. But it is not working, I think.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think if you run `./gradle` it uses the project Gradle but if you run `gradle` it uses the system Gradle.

Comment: Hi, It is automated by Android studio. Is there any option to change the flow?

Comment: I don't use Android Studio so I don't know.